# django test in travis CI

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I have a django project using travis CI

when I check pep8 in travis CI

It has no problem

and I want testing functional_test in travis CI

I insert the code in `.travis.yml`

**In `.travis.yml`**(hggg is a role name in my django project database)

```
language: python

python:
    - "3.5.1"

install: 
    - pip install -r requirement/development.txt

before_script:
    - createuser hggg

# # command to run tests
script:
    - pep8
    - python wef/manage.py test functional_test
```

but when build start

travis server can't create database

```
The command "pep8" exited with 0.
$ python wef/manage.py test users
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_bookconnect', or 'no' to cancel: 

No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

I want create a database(**postgresql**) in trvis CI

Please give me some advise

Comment: what script is trying to create the db? looks like the problem is there

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza oh, create database script? thank you i'll try

Comment: I insert `psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres` in before_script it has same error.. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: if you execute that psql command without the travis works?

Comment: yes, when I execute `psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres` in my terminal, it is has no problem ,, command line show `CREATE DATABASE`

Comment: what if you try again? because the error message show the database exist and now you change `test_bookconnect` to `travis_ci_test`. If the problem is database existe, just check for it or drop it before create a new one

Comment: um.... it is not about resolving this issue, but when i delete code `test functional_test` in script, and insert `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it has no problem,,, it sounds database migrating success,,,, So , I think this issue has problem in `functional_test`,,, I'll check about `functional_test` thank you @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: problem solved django test needs `test_database` so `hggg` must have `CREATE DATABASE` permission thank you @JuanCarlosOropeza